# Keras - Pop and re-add layers, but layer does not disconnect

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

Using Keras (1.2.2), I am loading a sequential model whose last layers are:

```
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Then, I want to pop the last layer, add another fully connected layer, and re-add the classification layer.

```
model = load_model('model1.h5')                                                                         
layer1 = model.layers.pop() # Copy activation_6 layer                                      
layer2 = model.layers.pop() # Copy classification layer (dense_2)                          

model.add(Dense(512, name='dense_3'))
model.add(Activation('softmax', name='activation_7'))

model.add(layer2)
model.add(layer1)

print(model.summary())
```

As you can see my dense_3 and activation_7 did not connect to the network (Empty value in summary() with "Connected to"). I cannot find anything in the documentation that explains how to solve this problem. Any ideas?

```
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 512)           131584      flatten_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)        (None, 512)           0           dense_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                  (None, 512)           5632                                         
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)        (None, 512)           0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 10)            5130        activation_5[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)        (None, 10)            0           dense_2[0][0]                    
====================================================================================================
```

Following the answer below, I compiled the model before printing out `model.summary()`, but for some reasons, the layers are not being popped correctly, as the summary shows: The last layer's connections are wrong:

```
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 512)           131584      flatten_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)        (None, 512)           0           dense_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                  (None, 512)           5632        activation_6[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)        (None, 512)           0           dense_3[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 10)            5130        activation_5[0][0]               
                                                                   activation_7[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)        (None, 10)            0           dense_2[0][0]                    
                                                                   dense_2[1][0]                    
====================================================================================================
```

But it should be

```
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 512)           131584      flatten_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)        (None, 512)           0           dense_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                  (None, 512)           5632        activation_5[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)        (None, 512)           0           dense_3[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 10)            5130                       
                                                                   activation_7[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)        (None, 10)            0           dense_2[0][0]                    

====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you drop layers, you need to recompile your model in order for it to have any effect.

So use

```
model.compile(loss=...,optimizer=..., ...)
```

before printing the summary and it should integrate the changes correctly.

**Edit :**

What you are trying to do is actually really complex with a Sequential mode. This is the solution I can come up with (if there is any better please tell me) for your Sequential model:

```
model = load_model('model1.h5')                                                                         
layer1 = model.layers.pop() # Copy activation_6 layer                                      
layer2 = model.layers.pop() # Copy classification layer (dense_2)                          

model.add(Dense(512, name='dense_3'))
model.add(Activation('softmax', name='activation_7'))

# get layer1 config
layer1_config = layer1.get_config()
layer2_config = layer2.get_config()
# change the name of the layers otherwise it complains
layer1_config['name'] = layer1_config['name'] + '_new'
layer2_config['name'] = layer2_config['name'] + '_new'

# import the magic function
from keras.utils.layer_utils import layer_from_config
# re-add new layers from the config of the old ones 
model.add(layer_from_config({'class_name':type(l2), 'config':layer2_config}))
model.add(layer_from_config({'class_name':type(l1), 'config':layer1_config}))

model.compile(...)

print(model.summary())
```

The hack is in the fact that your layers have `layer1.input` and `layer1.output` properties that I couldn't change.

A way around that is to use a Functionnal API model. This allows you to define what comes in and what goes out of your layers.

First you need to define your pop() function, to properly relink the layers every time you pop one, the function comes from [this github issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2640):

```
def pop_layer(model):
    if not model.outputs:
        raise Exception('Sequential model cannot be popped: model is empty.')

    popped_layer = model.layers.pop()
    if not model.layers:
        model.outputs = []
        model.inbound_nodes = []
        model.outbound_nodes = []
    else:
        model.layers[-1].outbound_nodes = []
        model.outputs = [model.layers[-1].output]
    model.built = False
    return popped_layer
```

it just removes every output links of the last layer and changes the outputs of the model to be the new last layer. Now you can use this in :

```
model = load_model('model1.h5')                                                                         
layer1 = model.layers.pop() # Copy activation_6 layer                                      
layer2 = model.layers.pop() # Copy classification layer (dense_2)     

# take model.outputs and feed a Dense layer
h = Dense(512,name='dense_3')(model.outputs)
h = Activation('relu', name=('activation_7')(h)
# apply
h = layer2(h)
output = layer1(h)

model = Model(input=model.input, output=output)
model.compile(...)
model.summary()
```

There are probably better solutions than this, but this is what I would do.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The compilation shows that I added the connections to the newly added layers (dense_3 and activation_7), but the connections to activation_6 and dense_2 seems to not have been updated by the pop(). I tried to compile after popping and once again after adding the next layers, with no effect. What I am missing here?

Comment: It does, and I learned a lot, thank you!  What I actually did before seeing your answer was to pop the layers, and instead of saving them, I re-added a new identical layer.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I need to build model with popped layer using Model before adding new layers to make things work.

```
conda list keras
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
keras                     2.1.5                    py36_0    conda-forge
```

Here is code snippet:

```
def pop_layer(model):
    if not model.outputs:
        raise Exception('Sequential model cannot be popped: model is empty.')

    model.layers.pop()
    if not model.layers:
        model.outputs = []
        model.inbound_nodes = []
        model.outbound_nodes = []
    else:
        model.layers[-1].outbound_nodes = []
        model.outputs = [model.layers[-1].output]
    model.built = False

def get_model():
    #Fully convolutional part of VGG16
    model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

    #Remove last max pooling layer
    pop_layer(model)

    #Freeze pretrained layers
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.outputs)

    print('len(model.layers)', len(model.layers)) #
    print(model.summary()) #

    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model.output)
    head = Dense(N_CLASS, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=head)

    model.compile(optimizer=Adadelta(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    print('len(model.layers)', len(model.layers)) #
    print(model.summary()) #

    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following function and it's working for my code:

```
for layer in model1.layers[:22]:
    model.add(layer)
```